# Increase of RPM meter after reaching my destination

Tags: toyota, camry, rpm

I'm driving Camry 2001 4 cylinder, automatic gear.

Just recently I noticed that after reaching my destination, when I put gear to P, I find the RPM meter increase to reach slightly lower than 2, which is not normal... Usually, it should at 1 or even less, even when I try to switch off the A/C or cassette, it's still up.

I'm not doing routine maintenance to my car, could this mean that I need to change gear oil??

Comment: When you have put it in park, try pressing the throttle and letting it off very quickly (slide your foot off, so it springs back up).  Do the revs drop down?